# Face recognition Intel Perceptual Computing

Tags: c++, intel, perception, perceptual-sdk

I am a newbie working with INTEL PERCEPTUAL COMPUTING SDK Gold version released in 2013. I am using visual studio 2012 professional version and I am using c++ samples. I have figured out a way to detect faces of people when they come in front of the camera. Now I am developing a SECURITY application which will allow user authentication after FACIAL RECOGNITION.
How can I store & compare faces detected by camera on runtime?

Answer (score 3):

i work at the studio of the perceptual computing sdk.

all i can say is:

1. you have a function called FaceAnalysis.CreateModel() which allows you to generate a model (haar cascade) of the face. this can be saved in a database after serialization (FaceAnalysis.Serialize() ).

2. you can compare that model the current face in real time by using the FaceAnalysis.Compare() function. this can give you the option to compare the current identified face model to the ones exist in the database and if they are not exist then...

3. important note: that face recognition uses 2D capabilities. therefore, if you show the sensor a picture of a guy you have in your database, it probably would fool the sensor as if that person sat in that chair. therefore, you should not productize that exact version (because it can be fooled).

hope i helped and good luck.
we would love to hear what you think of the development process and on the api.

Comment: Thank you for such quick response. I will try your method and will get back asap.

Comment: I am facing terrible issues in connecting VISUAL C++ (visual studio professional version 2012) with mysql.
And is there any way of saving voice commands in text file for voice recognition module?
Thank you.